# Rack aware Kafka: reassignment of partitions not including all racks

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to convert a non-rack-aware kafka config to be rack-aware. My setup is as follows:

6 brokers, across 3 different aws AZs in the same region (2 brokers in each AZ).

```
- AZ-1a
     broker1 (brokerID: 1) has setting 'broker.rack=aws-az-1a'
     broker2 (brokerID: 2) has setting 'broker.rack=aws-az-1a'

- AZ-1b
     broker3 (brokerID: 3) has setting 'broker.rack=aws-az-1b'
     broker4 (brokerID: 4) has setting 'broker.rack=aws-az-1b'
- AZ-1c
     broker5 (brokerID: 5) has setting 'broker.rack=aws-az-1c'
     broker6 (brokerID: 6) has setting 'broker.rack=aws-az-1c'
```

That's 3 racks in total with 2 brokers in each.

I have a kafka topic 'xyz' with 12 partitions, and a replication factor of 3.

Previously we were guaranteed to have a replica in more than one AZ due to the replication factor exceeding the number of brokers (3 vs 2) in any particular AZ.

However, making our configuration rack aware, I want it to be so I have 1 replica in each of the 3 AZs.

I generate a 'partition-reassignment-configuration' file, as follows;

```
./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper $ZK --generate --topics-to-move-json-file topics-to-move.json --broker-list '1,2,3,4,5,6'
```

where topics-to-move.json contains:

```
{"topics": [{"topic": "xyz"}],
 "version":1
}
```

)

The problem I am having is that the output I receive when I generate the 'Proposed partition reassignment configuration', seems to pick brokers from only 2 AZs/racks. It always follows that it picks one rack, then another, then the first rack again.

ie: rack1, rack2, rack1

My feeling is that I'm missing something subtle. On updating the properties file on each broker with a value for 'broker.rack', kafka was restarted. However, I am still unable to get the 'Proposed partition reassignement configuration', to span all 3 racks (one replica per rack).

There doesn't appear to be a lot of documentation out there about this (which leads me to believe it should be very straight-forward). However, so far I have been unable to achieve a fully rack-aware config.

Comment: Further details to add. Kafka version is 2.11-1.1.1. And, when topics were originally created there were only 3 brokers. I've subsequently added 3 more and am trying to reassign topics across all.

Comment: I've investigated this further. It turns out that adding the 'broker.rack' setting to the properties file, by itself, is not enough. Checking the broker properties in zookeeper, this change is not reflected there. So, it seems my problem now is how to update the broker information, as recorded in zookeeper, with this new information.

Comment: Further to this. On the broker side, when starting kafka, I can see the broker.rack value in the server.log logfile. Information about the broker gets newly written to zookeeper every time kafka starts. However, it is not including any rack information. According to this doc - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper  - 'rack' is now part of the schema (since version 0.10). However, it is not appearing for me, despite using version 0.11

Comment: Mystery solved. Despite using a version of kafka that supports rack-awareness I have been deliberately setting 'inter.broker.protocol.version' to an older version (due to various issues with some of our consumers). When I update this parameter to use a later version, I can see 'rack' being written to zookeeper.

For now I need to turn my attention to resolving the issues with my consumers.